# Если открывается страница кроном то не парсится

Tags: php, парсер

Извлекаю информацию из постов из блога, где есть видео с тэгом `<video> </video>`.

Вот код примерный

```
preg_match('/regexp/s',$html,$video);
    $vidos = $video[0];
    echo $vidos ;
```

Если в браузере запускать скрипт, парсится нормально сам тэг, включая source, но вот если крон запускает скрипт, то видео записывается в переменную без тэгов source.

В кроне задача стоит `wget http://site.ru/script.php` каждую минуту.

Comment: не уверен точно но может крон "занимает" собой (своим процессом) источник ($video)?

Comment: покажите часть скрипта, которая получает данные. 
работа с файлами там есть?

Comment: чисто $html = file_get_contents

Comment: и попробуйте с такими параметрами: wget -qO- http://site.ru/script.php

Comment: добавления параметра не решило проблему(

Comment: cron тут, скорее всего, ни при чём. вероятно, такой же результат вы получите и при запуске той же команды из оболочки. кстати, что значит «запустить скрипт с браузера»?

Comment: переход по ссылке скрипта из браузера

Comment: Можно попробовать curl c заголовками нормального браузера.

Comment: сделал curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"); та же фигня(

Comment: попробовал через node.js та же история(

Comment: а если попробовать не через wget?
/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/site.ru/script.php